# Dynamic T-SQL stored procedure in where clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to write a sample stored procedure with 2 parameters like this:

```
sp_list_customers @locationid int, @category varchar
```

Users can pass in the `@locationid = 0` to list down customers in ALL locations or specific location ID. Also they can pass null or empty string to p to slow ALL categories.

Here is my SQL code:

```
create procedure ...
as 
    select * 
    from customers
    where locationid = (case 
                           when isnull(@locationid, 0) = 0 
                              then locationid 
                              else @locationid  
                        end)
      and category = (case 
                         when isnull(@category, '') = '' 
                            then category 
                            else @category 
                      end)
```

However this kind of codes is running toooo slow with more parameters

I was looking for ways to fix the issue and then found out the dynamic T-SQL is the acceptable solution. But to migrate all my stored procedures is a nightmare job and error prone.

I need to write another user defined function to help me. What is the best user-defined function code for this?

Thanks

Comment: http://sqlsentry.tv/the-kitchen-sink-procedure/

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Depending on how often the proc is called, a `RECOMPILE` hint may be the easiest solution: `WHERE (@locationid IS NULL OR @locationid = 0 OR locationid = @locationid) AND (@category IS NULL OR @category = '' OR category = @category) OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) is a must read on this subject...

Comment: Aside: Assuming that `@LocationId` cannot be `0` then your first `case` expression can be replaced with `Coalesce( @LocationId, LocationId )`. This avoids the bad habit of introducing a _magic number_, i.e. `0`, that will _never_ occur in the real data. It often turns up in dates, e.g. we'll never insure a building that was built in 1600. Which castle?

Answer (score 0):

Try if the below simplified code works better...

```
create procedure ... as select * from customers where (nullif(@locationid,'') is null
  or locationid = @locationid)
 and (   nullif(@category,'') is null or category = @category)
```

Comment: But we are using the NULLIF on variable not on the column of the table, so I believe that shouldn't cause any issues ...

Comment: True, but I'd misread; this does become a catch-all query though, or what Aaron Bertrand refers to an "the kitchen sink", which have do have performance problems. Normally the better solution is to use dynamic SQL as a result.

Comment: Thank you @Larnu for pointing out about "the kitchen sink" pattern, I just read what it is. But somehow in my limited experience I had I always had nightmare experiences with dynamic queries. But I agree with what 'Aaron' mentioned in that article.